# Displaying annotation in older versions of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, annotation, arcgis-10.5

I created an annotation layer in a trial of 10.5 that will not open in 10.0. I don't see why this should be as the annotation resides in my fgdb and not a map document.

When I try to open it in 10.0 I get the following error:

*"Item does not have a definition. The XML being loaded could not be parsed."*

The associated layer opens fine.

Answer (score 1):

As a test I think you should use the [Create File GDB](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-file-gdb.htm) tool from ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 to create an empty file geodatabase for ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Then, still using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 use the Catalog window to copy/paste your annotation feature class into the 10.0 file geodatabase.

I am hopeful that this may then be opened in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Comment: I rather try to import (or export) than Copy/paste, but yes creating a file database compatible with 10.0 seem the way to go.